# log4net:ERROR Appender named [loki] not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, grafana-loki, log4net-appender

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC (4.7.2) application and have integrated log4net for logging purposes. I am trying to configure a custom appender called "loki" using the **log4net.Appender.Loki** nuget package, but I'm facing an issue with it. The issue is that the ***"console"*** and ***"file"*** logging is working perfectly as expected, but the "loki" appender is giving me the following error:

```
log4net: ERROR Appender named [loki] not found
```

I have added the **log4net.Appender.Loki** package, and I have defined the "loki" appender in my configuration. It's perplexing because the other appenders are working as intended.

Here's my log4net configuration:

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
    <appender-ref ref="loki" />
  </root>

  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="loki" type="log4net.Appender.LokiAppender, log4net.Appender.Loki">
    <BufferSize  value="3" />
    <ServiceUrl value="http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push" />
    <BasicAuthUserName value="" />
    <BasicAuthPassword value="" />
    <TrustSelfCignedCerts value="false" />
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="myapp.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```